# Hide Content Builder folders

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it somehow possible to hide certain content builder folders within one BU for special users?

We want our Sales team to create their own campaigns, without seeing the whole folder structure of our whole marketing folder structure

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Enterprise 2.0 account, you can add the contents to to a shared folder and restrict users from been able to view the shared folders or vice versa. What you cant do is restrict permissions on individuals folders.

[image]